# Email is not delivering in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

I am trying to send email in my rails app and  in logs I have seen following body

```
Sent mail to ravendra.kumar@kiwitech.com (97ms)
Date: Wed, 25 Feb 2015 08:13:57 +0000
From: ashish.singla@kiwitech.com
To: ravendra.kumar@kiwitech.com
Message-ID: <54ed84452dcca_71c16217f47382e@web-01-development.mail>
Subject: Ashish Singla is inviting you to read together...
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

but email is not delivering.

Comment: Can you share more details, like the contents of of you development.rb file where you have set the email credentials.

Comment: The default setting for the development environment is not to deliver mails. Did you change that?

Comment: i am sending using delayedjob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least your mailer class is working.
If you are in development mode, ensure that you have the `perform_deliveries` option set to true.

If not, go to your `config/environments/development.rb` file and write

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

If this setting is already set to true and you are not getting the emails, then probably your smtp settings are not properly set. You can set them in `config/application.rb` with something like following:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.office365.com',
  :port           => 587,
  :domain         => 'your-domain.com',
  :user_name      => 'user@your-domain.com',
  :password       => 'somePassword',
  authentication: :login,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

In this case, may be enabling the setting `raise_delivery_errors` will help you to diagnose problems. You can do that in your `config/environments/development.rb` file and writing:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Then you will get an exception when the email can't be sent and (hopefully) a description about the problem.

And after reading your comment: after changing all these config settings, restart the delayed_job backend.